# Use MeasureIt value in driver

Tags: add-on, drivers, measurement

Do values from the MeasureIt add-on have a data path we can point to when using drivers ?
I've scrolled through the code but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I think you can. You can right click any value field in the advanced options (the cogwheel icon next to the eye icon) of any MeasureIt measurement, and then choose Add Driver. Or choose Copy Data Path to use in the Single Property Driver Variable Type of an excising driver.

Comment: Unless I have no eyes, there is no UI element containing the value of a measurement. It's only displayed in the viewport.
If measured values have a data path, they are hidden and can only be found in the python code.

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean. My knowledge is very lacking on this point but then isn't the data you're referring to the actual mesh data? I suspect that in a way the 3Dviewport displayed MeasureIt values are "driven" by mesh geometry, and that there isn't separate MeasureIt data that defines the mesh dimensions; Because one can't edit mesh geometry via MeasureIt UI. (but like I said i don;t really know.)

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway. But yeah in theory I could write math formulas as driver expressions to get the same results as what MeasureIt does but in practice it would come out as unreasonably long driver expressions. Or I could split expressions in multiple parts by adding more objects and using their properties to nest the different parts of the expressions. Or I could just write a python script that does the same as MeasureIt except it puts the results in properties that are accessible from python, which may be the most reasonable solution. I was just hoping MeasureIt already had this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered [custom functions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#custom-function-square-value) which are a way to expand driver functions using python. This way I can use any complex geometrical calculation in a driver with the help of numpy and math.